# how to poplate jtable with jtextfield values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have a `JTexTField` which searches for item details and displays a single row using `keyReleased` `ActionListener` in a `JTable` whenever a barcode is entered in the text field.

My goal is to add multiple rows in this `JTable` through this `JTextField`. For example if a barcode is scanned or entered in the text field, a row should added in the `JTable` and also the text field also cleared for the next scan.

I can achieve this with a button to add a row but my challenge is to add row in a `JTable` whenever a barcode is entered. below is my code. so far i can search and poplate the table with only one code.
   private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

```
    try {
        String sql = "select barcode,serv_descr,serv_amt,notes from service.servicces where barcode=?";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        Table_servicesale.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is little difference between using a `JButton` and `ActionListener` and using a `JTextField` and a `ActionListener`

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: try {
            String sql = "select barcode,serv_descr,serv_amt,notes from service.servicces where barcode=?";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            Table_servicesale.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }

Comment: So you "main" problem is the reliance on `DbUtils` to do the work which you should be doing.  `DbUtils` creates a new `TableModel` each time it's called, which is not what you want to do

Comment: hello, this is my code. so far i can search and poplate the table with only on row. but i want to use  this search textfield to insert many rows in the jtable when the user scans a barcode. please help .

Comment: private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
       
        try {
            String sql = "select barcode,serv_descr,serv_amt,notes from service.servicces where barcode=?";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            Table_servicesale.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }

Comment: I discourage the use of `KeyListener`s with any text component and instead would recommend using a `DocumentListener`

Comment: please kindly help me to rewrite my code using documentListener.  am not farmiliar with it and also the liblary to import. thanks

Comment: [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners)

Answer (score 1):

You should populate the jtable through a table model. have a look here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

You should create a class that will implement the TableModel interface. In this class you will update the number of rows in the table.